# Do/Are we stay in hotels?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to know which is correct form to write this sentences and the reason for that.

Examples:

> Do we stay in hotels?
> Are we stay in hotels?

> Do I need shoes?
> Am I need shoes?

I need to understand the differences and know which one is the correct form.

Comment: When we use auxiliary TO DO in these contexts, the "primary" verb *(**stay, need**)* is in the ***infinitive*** form (but without the "infinitive marker" ***to** stay, **to** need*). With auxiliary TO BE, the primary verb has the ***continuous participle*** form: *Are we **staying** in hotels?, Am I **needing** shoes?* But that last one isn't actually very natural / idiomatic in English, for obscure reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a statement into a question, you [invert the subject and auxiliary verb/modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion).

> You must eat.
> Must you eat?

If there is no auxiliary verb, you add **do** as an auxiliary verb, and then carry out the inversion:

> You eat.
> You do eat.
> Do you eat?

There is one exception: if there is no auxiliary/modal and the main verb is **be**, you invert the subject and main verb:

> You are ready.
> Are you ready?

For your sentences, there is no auxiliary verb and the main verb is not **be**, so you add **do** and then invert:

> We stay in hotels.
> Do we stay in hotels?
>
> I need shoes.
> Do I need shoes?

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, it is very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The verb “**do**” is used **with the infinitive form of the main verb** to form questions in

1 **The simple  present tense**

I live in England -> <s>Live I in England?</s> **Do** I live in England?

I speak English -> <s>Speak I English?"</s> **Do** I speak English?

2 **The simple past:**

I lived in England -> <s>Lived I in England?</s> **Did** I live in England?

I spoke English -> <s>Spoke I English?"</s> **Did** I speak English?

3a

**Do** is **not** used with the present or past perfect:

I have bought a car - <s>Do/did I have/had bought a car?</s> - Have/had I bought a car?

3b

**Do** is **not** used with the continuous form of the verb:

I am speaking English - <s>Do I be speaking English?</s> Am I speaking English?

4

The verb **Do** is **not** used with the verb to be:

I am tall - <s>Do I be tall?</s> - Am I tall?

He was angry - <s>Did he be angry?</s> - Was he angry?

5.
The verb **Do** is **optional** with the verb **to have** if “have” means to own or possess:

I have a dog – Have I a dog? / Do I have a dog?
I had no money – Had I no money? / Did I have no money?

**Are we stay in hotels? / Am I need shoes?** These are wrong. We do not use **am/to be** in this way.

Comment: Thank you so much for you complete answer, it is very useful for me.